# In SVG Path Arc: find angle at start and end point

Tags: java, svg, angle

Given the parameters porvided by SVG Path for an arc

SVG reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d#Elliptical_Arc_Curve

Simulation: http://xahlee.info/js/svg_circle_arc.html

How would you find the angle between the tangent line at start or end point and a horizontal line that goes through either the start or end point depending on which angle you try to find in Java?

Comment: get the arc position at the start and the arc position at a point a small delta from the start and use trigonometry to find the start angle. Repeat for the end.

Comment: How would I find the small delta? The coordinates for the start and end point are provided so I don´t have to find them.

Comment: in mathematics delta means a tiny number, pick something suitable.

Comment: I am aware of what delta means. My question is: how would I find a fitting value?

Comment: Choose something small enough that it's sufficiently accurate for your use case.

Comment: How would I find a point that is on the arc though?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#__svg__SVGGeometryElement__getPointAtLength